# list of objects, how to combine objects that have two keys have the same values

Tags: terraform

I am creating a module that creates IAM roles. the consumer will be providing something like this

```
role_cross_account_config = [{
     account_ids     = ["1111112222222","333332222222"]
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = ["845666666666"]
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = ["7777788888888","6666444444444"]
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = ["555564444444"]
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = ["3333399997777"]
     external_id = null
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = ["64558888888","24331551111","77788644433"]
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 }]
```

I am trying to combine all objects that have the same values for `external_id` and `require_mfa` into one object with all `account_ids`

So I should get something like this

```
new_list = [{
     account_ids     = ["1111112222222","333332222222","555564444444","64558888888","24331551111","77788644433"]
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = ["845666666666","7777788888888","6666444444444"]
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = ["3333399997777"]
     external_id = null
     require_mfa = true
 }]
```

I am able to do it but only for those that share the same value for `require_mfa` and `external_id = null` and that's by using for loop and if else logic. I squeezed my mind to find a way for this but could not come up with any solution so far

NOTE:

- `require_mfa` is boolean
- `external_id` is string
- The `external_id`  could have any value. Meaning the consumer could enter as many objects with whatever `external_id` they choose. I am trying to combine any objects that share the same value for external_id and also for require_mfa.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Terraform supports a few functions (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions.html) but it's missing a few important ones, such as the groupBy that you'd need.

Comment: @TamásSallai I actually came up with a way to solve it and I posted it here. Can you please review it and let me know if you have any criticism about it?

Comment: You're right, the for expression can work. Nice solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually was able to find a solution for it and I will post it so it might benefit someone one day..

First I had to change the module so it will be taking an object for each `account_id` instead of having a list of `account_ids` in every object. like this:

```
role_cross_account_config = [{
     account_ids     = "333332222222"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "333332222222"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "845666666666"
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = "7777788888888"
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = "6666444444444"
     external_id = "dsaa"
     require_mfa = false
 },{
     account_ids     = "555564444444"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "3333399997777"
     external_id = null
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "64558888888"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "24331551111"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 },{
     account_ids     = "77788644433"
     external_id = "yesss"
     require_mfa = true
 }]
```

I used local variables to solve it. Since I am trying to group by two conditions and since one of them is boolean so if I divide the list into two different lists one for the boolean true and one for the boolean false. Then I worked on each list and grouped by the second condition using `"for"` along with `"if"`. I had to use distinct because my way would result in many duplicates.

`NOTE:` this method would be considered garbage in any programming language because it's time and resource wasting but this is the only way I could find in Terraform as it's still too limited language. I believe such a thing will become much easier in the near future as Terraform is stll growing and evolving.

```
locals {
  list_no_mfa = [for s in var.role_cross_account_config : 
          {
            external_id = s.external_id
            require_mfa = s.require_mfa
            account_ids = s.account_ids
          }
        if s.require_mfa != true]

  no_mfa_same_id = distinct([for s in local.list_no_mfa : 
          {
            external_id = s.external_id
            require_mfa = s.require_mfa
            account_ids = [for i in local.list_no_mfa : i.account_ids if i.external_id == s.external_id]
          }
        ])

  list_mfa = [for s in var.role_cross_account_config : 
          {
            external_id = s.external_id
            require_mfa = s.require_mfa
            account_ids = s.account_ids
          }
        if s.require_mfa != false]

  mfa_same_id = distinct([for s in local.list_mfa : 
          {
            external_id = s.external_id
            require_mfa = s.require_mfa
            account_ids = [for i in local.list_mfa : i.account_ids if i.external_id == s.external_id]
          }
        ])

  combined_list = concat(local.no_mfa_same_id, local.mfa_same_id)
}
```

Now the `local.combined_list` is the wished result.

Comment: Nice! I'm wondering why you need 4 variables. I tried this, and it seems like doing the same:
sorted = distinct([for s in var.role_cross_account_config :
                {
                        external_id = s.external_id
                        require_mfa = s.require_mfa
                        account_ids = flatten([for i in local.role_cross_account_config : i.account_ids if i.external_id == s.external_id && i.require_mfa == s.require_mfa])
                }
        ])
}

Comment: @TamásSallai Your way is much much nicer than mine.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note before going into the answer, your key/value pairs are written as variables, so you aren't actually able to access them the same way you would as an object key value pair. So, having said that, if you convert those '=' to ':' you can do this:

```
new_list = [{
    account_ids: [],
  external_id: "yesss",
  require_mfa: true
},{
    account_ids: [],
  external_id: "dsaa",
  require_mfa: false
},{
    account_ids: [],
  external_id: null,
  require_mfa: false
}]

role_cross_account_config = [{
     account_ids : ["1111112222222","333332222222"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["845666666666"],
     external_id : "dsaa",
     require_mfa : false
 },{
     account_ids : ["7777788888888","6666444444444"],
     external_id : "dsaa",
     require_mfa : false
 },{
     account_ids : ["555564444444"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["3333399997777"],
     external_id : null,
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["64558888888","24331551111","77788644433"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 }]
 
  for (let i = 0; i < role_cross_account_config.length; i++) {
    if (role_cross_account_config[i]['external_id'] === 'yesss' && role_cross_account_config[i]['require_mfa'] === true) {
    for (let j = 0; j < role_cross_account_config[i]['account_ids'].length; j++) {
        new_list[0]['account_ids'].push(role_cross_account_config[i]['account_ids'][j])      
    }
  }
 }
 
 console.log(new_list)
```

You can add on to the 'if' statement using else to look for other combinations like "dsaa" and "false", "dsaa" and "true". Whatever combinations you're looking to compare.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry I think I did not make it clear in my question. the `external_id ` could have any value. Meaning the consumer could enter as many objects with whatever `external_id ` they choose. I am trying to combine any objects that share the same value for `external_id ` and also for `require_mfa`. TBh I am not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Please check my new answer below, I understand what you want and found a solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

Now that I understand what you need better, I've found a solution for you. You will need to create a function to make it work. The same issue I mentioned before still applies, you need this to be true object key/value pairs with ':' instead of '='.

Basically, the code iterates through your array of objects 'role_cross...' and compares the 'external id' and 'require_mfa' to all other objects within the array. If it finds a match for both, it stores those values in a seperate array called "checkedVal". Function "alreadyChecked" checks "checkedVal" before iterating if the combination (ex: yesss and true) has been checked, and if it has, moves on to the next object to compare.

Once it passes all the checks, it creates a new 'object' within the 'new_list' array with predefined keys. This makes it really easy to then add the appropriate values to the newly created object within the array. Let me know if you have questions about any part.

I think that should solve it for you. Here's the code:

```
let new_list = [{}]
let checkedVal = [['init1','init2']]
let nextNewEntry = 0

role_cross_account_config = [{
     account_ids : ["1111112222222","333332222222"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["845666666666"],
     external_id : "dsaa",
     require_mfa : false
 },{
     account_ids : ["7777788888888","6666444444444"],
     external_id : "dsaa",
     require_mfa : false
 },{
     account_ids : ["555564444444"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["3333399997777"],
     external_id : null,
     require_mfa : true
 },{
     account_ids : ["64558888888","24331551111","77788644433"],
     external_id : "yesss",
     require_mfa : true
 }]
 
  function alreadyChecked(external, mfa) {
    for (k=0; k < checkedVal.length; k++) {
        
        if (checkedVal[k][0] === external && checkedVal[k][1] === mfa) {
          console.log('Already checked this combination '+external+' '+mfa)
          return true
      } else if (k === checkedVal.length -1) {
            console.log('Have not checked this yet '+external+' '+mfa)
            return false
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < role_cross_account_config.length; i++) {
    if (alreadyChecked(role_cross_account_config[i]['external_id'],role_cross_account_config[i]['require_mfa'])===false) {
    console.log('moving forward with the iterations')
    nextNewEntry++;
    checkedVal[nextNewEntry-1] = []
    checkedVal[nextNewEntry-1].push(role_cross_account_config[i]['external_id'],role_cross_account_config[i]['require_mfa'])
    new_list[nextNewEntry-1] = {
    account_ids: [],
    external_id: '',
    require_mfa: ''
    }   
        for (let j = 0; j < role_cross_account_config.length; j++) {
        
        
            if (role_cross_account_config[i]['external_id'] === role_cross_account_config[j]['external_id'] && role_cross_account_config[i]['require_mfa'] === role_cross_account_config[j]['require_mfa']) {
          
            for (let h = 0; h < role_cross_account_config[j]['account_ids'].length; h++) {
            new_list[nextNewEntry-1]['account_ids'].push(role_cross_account_config[j]['account_ids'][h]);
            new_list[nextNewEntry-1]['external_id'] = role_cross_account_config[i]['external_id'];
            new_list[nextNewEntry-1]['require_mfa'] = role_cross_account_config[i]['require_mfa'];                 
            }           
            }
            
      }
      
    }    
  }
 
 console.log(new_list)
 console.log(checkedVal)
```

Comment: you can remove the "if (j != i || j = i)" that's wrapped around the section of code that assigns values to the "new_list". I did that while testing some errors but ultimately proved to be inconsequential.

Comment: @Data_sniffer I went ahead and edited the code and removed it.

Comment: Thanks again for you answer. Is this Terraform? I am working on Terraform here