# Terraform merge objects based on some field

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects described below
Two users are identical if they have the same `(username, rolearn)` pair
If it makes things easier, users can be considered identical if the have the same `username` or `rolearn` as well

The roles have to be added to a list for each identical user

Input:

```
user_list_admin = [
  {
    username = "user1"
    rolearn  = "arn1"
    groups   = [
      "system:admin"
    ]
  },
  {
    username = "user2"
    rolearn  = "arn2"
    groups   = [
      "system:admin"
    ]
  },
]

user_list_read_only = [
  {
    username = "user2"
    rolearn  = "arn2"
    groups   = [
      "system:read-only"
    ]
  },
]
```

output:

```
user_list_all_rols = [
  {
    username = "user1"
    rolearn  = "arn1"
    groups   = [
      "system:admin"
    ]
  },
  {
    username = "user2"
    rolearn  = "arn2"
    groups   = [
      "system:admin",
      "system:read-only"
    ]
  },
]
```

I tried to turn this into a `map{user => group}` and reduce it, but I'm quite new to Terraform, so i didn't manage this

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with the help of [list of objects, how to combine objects that have two keys have the same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069541/list-of-objects-how-to-combine-objects-that-have-two-keys-have-the-same-values)

Solution below
I had to change the format of my input

```
user_list_admin = [
  {
    username = "user1"
    rolearn  = "arn1"
    group    = "system:admin"
  },
  {
    username = "user2"
    rolearn  = "arn2"
    group    = "system:admin"
  },
]

user_list_read_only = [
  {
    username = "user2"
    rolearn  = "arn2"
    group    = "system:read-only"
  },
]

users = concat(
  user_list_admin,
  user_list_read_only,
)

users_merged_groups = distinct([
  for user in local.users :
  {
    rolearn  = user.rolearn
    username = user.username
    groups = [
      for u in local.users : u.group if u.rolearn == user.rolearn
    ]
  }
])
```